# how to mark ampersand and apostrophe safe in AntiXss?

Tags: c#, antixsslibrary

I am currently using the Microsoft AntiXSS library and encoding HTML using HtmlEncode method. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244070(v=vs.110).aspx), ampersand and apostrophe are not part of the safe list. I want to add them to the safe list. It seems like it is possible by using [MarkAsSafe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder.markassafe(v=vs.110).aspx). However, I am not able to figure out how to do so. How can I add these to the safe list?

Comment: I'm not sure `&` can ever be safe, given that it's the basis of declaring and using HTML entities such as `&amp;` etc.

Comment: Are you saying that you are trying to get it to _not_ encode ampersands? Why?

Comment: @JLRishe I save user input that I encode in my db. When I then pull it out of the db and show it in UI, it is getting encoded again, ie in my db it is saved as `A &amp; B` but in the UI it is show as `A &amp;amp; B`

Comment: @MikyasGami Ok, so the problem is that your data values are being encoded twice. That's the problem you need to solve. You're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Ok, I see that double encoding is happening. However, I would still like a way to save ampersand and apostrophe without encoding. If I can't use Microsoft AntiXss, is there some other thing I can use?

Comment: @MikyasGami It sounds like maybe you shouldn't be encoding the value before you store it. Is there a reason you want to store the value with HTML encoding?

Comment: @MikyasGami It actually doesn't matter what text you **store** in your database whether it's "safe" or "unsafe". It's just text at this point, nothing more. It only becomes dangerous when you render it back to the browser without proper escaping. All you need to do is make absolutely sure that when you render it back into the browser, you correctly escape the data for the context in which it is shown. It's fine to have data in your DB that reads `<script src="badstuff"></script>`, as long as you escape it when you render....

Comment: ... so that the browser doesn't recognise the rendered data as control characters. It looks like your view engine already does this if you're seeing double encoding, but make sure you double check. Anyway... you don't need to escape the data as it goes in. Only as it gets rendered back out.