# How to mark ampersand and apostrophe safe in AntiXssEncoder?

Tags: c#, .net, html-encode, antixsslibrary

Same a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49200004/how-to-mark-ampersand-and-apostrophe-safe-in-antixss), but my issue is different.

I have a string with and & and ' that displaying their reference codes on the webpage. I need to get it to show the original characters, not the codes.

```
AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode("Mike's & Sallies Shop", true)
```

Output:

```
Mike&#39;s &amp; Sallies Shop
```

Comment: But why? I mean if it should be html, let it be. If it is being parsed by some program (and you truly need `'` there, why do you `HtmlEncode()` it?

Comment: I believe the string can sometimes be bolded, and we use <b> tags  in the string for that

Answer (score 0):

For others who might have this problem, I found [Decoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Web_HttpUtility_HtmlDecode_System_String_) the string to work. My new code is below:

```
StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode("Mike's & Sallies Shop", true), myWriter);
<p>myWriter.toString()</p>
```

Output is:

```
Mike's & Sallies Shop
```

EDIT: and even easier solution:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode("Mike's & Sallies Shop", true))
```

Comment: Well, have you tried to put `<b>` inside? Does it have the expected output?